# When is a Gaussian field almost surely bounded?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $p\ge1$ and assume given a (deterministic) function
$$
R:\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}
$$
such that $R$ is symmetric, meaning that $R(x,y)=R(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^p$, and such that $R$ is positive semidefinite, meaning that for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in\mathbb{R}$, it holds that
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\xi_i R(x_i,x_j)\xi_j\ge0.
$$
It is then well known that there exists a separable mean zero Gaussian field $W$ with $R$ as its covariance function, meaning that $W$ has finite-dimensional Gaussian distributions and $\textrm{Cov}(W(x),W(y))=R(x,y)$, see for example Chapter 5 of D. Khoshnevisan: "Multiparameter processes". Separability implies that the supremum $\|W\|_\infty$ is well-defined, see also Lifshits: "Gaussian Random Functions". I am interested in conditions for when this supremum is almost surely finite and has a continuous distribution, or equivalently, has a continuous CDF (the distribution of $\|W\|_\infty$ is of interest for nonparametric testing, as it for certain Gaussian fields appear as a limiting statistic for a Kolmogorov-Smirnov type test in the multidimensional case). Several results on the distribution of $\|W\|_\infty$ exists when $\|W\|_\infty$ is almost surely finite. However, it is not clear to me when this is the case.

$\textbf{My question:}$ What are sufficient criteria on $R$ to ensure that $\|W\|_\infty$ is almost surely finite? In particular, does it hold that if $x\mapsto R(x,x)$ is bounded, then $\|W\|_\infty$ is almost surely finite?

Note that $R$ is not assumed to be continuous in the above, and nor is it assumed that $W$ has a continuous modification. Theorem 2.4 of Marcus & Shepp: "Sample behaviour of Gaussian processes" gives a bound on the distribution which would imply that $\|W\|_\infty$ is almost surely finite when $x\mapsto R(x,x)$ is bounded. Unfortunately, the result presupposes that $\|W\|_\infty$ is almost surely finite.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: This is not an answer but only a comment. I recently have encountered the same problem. It seems that many results simply assume a.s. boundedness. I think path continuity certainly guarantees that. Stationary increment and certain restrictions on the covariance function are sufficient to ensure path continuity. However in my problem, the Gaussian process does not have stationary increment. So I still need more general conditions for a.s. boundedness.